# HQL agg execution got ‘Unable to load credentials from service endpoint’ error

Tags: ssl, amazon-s3, hive, minio

I use minio as the hive storage system, and there is no problem when I execute query statements like 'select * from table'.
But when I execute agg query like 'select max(age) from student',then I got an error:

```
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: hive: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.auth.NoAuthWithAWSException: No AWS Credentials provided by SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider : com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load credentials from service endpoint
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.translateException(S3AUtils.java:187)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.once(Invoker.java:111)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.lambda$retry$3(Invoker.java:265)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.retryUntranslated(Invoker.java:322)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.retry(Invoker.java:261)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.retry(Invoker.java:236)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.verifyBucketExists(S3AFileSystem.java:375)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.initialize(S3AFileSystem.java:311)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3303)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:124)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3352)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3320)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:479)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:361)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.isEmptyPath(Utilities.java:2610)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.isEmptyPath(Utilities.java:2606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities$GetInputPathsCallable.call(Utilities.java:3432)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.getInputPaths(Utilities.java:3370)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecDriver.execute(ExecDriver.java:359)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask.execute(MapRedTask.java:149)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:205)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:97)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:2664)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:2335)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:2011)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1709)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1703)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.reexec.ReExecDriver.run(ReExecDriver.java:157)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.reexec.ReExecDriver.run(ReExecDriver.java:218)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:239)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:188)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:402)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:821)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:759)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:683)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:323)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.auth.NoAuthWithAWSException: No AWS Credentials provided by SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider : com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load credentials from service endpoint
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AWSCredentialProviderList.getCredentials(AWSCredentialProviderList.java:159)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.getCredentialsFromContext(AmazonHttpClient.java:1166)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.runBeforeRequestHandlers(AmazonHttpClient.java:762)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:724)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:717)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4368)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4315)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.headBucket(AmazonS3Client.java:1344)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.doesBucketExist(AmazonS3Client.java:1284)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.lambda$verifyBucketExists$1(S3AFileSystem.java:376)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.once(Invoker.java:109)
        ... 39 more
```

Should I add some config in my fs system?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the same issue facing by us. You can open a tunnel from your local machine to the amazon instance to check the access.

In medium an article says a custom class kind of solution.
https://medium.com/expedia-group-tech/service-slow-to-retrieve-aws-credentials-ebc02a38e95b